# VS 2015: How to debug Access Violation from MSVCR120.dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, sqlite

I am working on a VS 2015 MVC C# web application for a client. The application has been stable for a couple of years, but the client has asked me to integrate some C++ DLLs that perform engineering calculations relevant to our web application.

Unfortunately there is no source code and documentation does not exist (don't ask me why...). So I am somewhat blind to how to use these DLLs.

When I load the main DLL and attempt to use it I get the following error:

```
Failed to load library SQLite3Ex.dll
```

Event viewer contains this entry:

```
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.10557.1000, time stamp: 0x560abee8
Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524f7ce6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000f20c
Faulting process id: 0x1450
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1c6773bd1167d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll
Report Id: 5d46a86a-2202-4d6e-af41-8426c16966e9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this problem and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I think this is a general error - could be a missing .cfg file or even a missing DLL? But I'm not sure how to determine the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing SQlite is a dependency - is it installed?

Comment: Assuming that you have a sqlite3ex.dll somewhere that it can be loaded, have you run Dependency Walker ("depends.exe") on it to figure out if it has its own dependencies that can't be loaded? You could also try running Process Monitor while testing the app to see the progress of the DLL search.

Comment: Oddly, @ravuya an similar question cropped up a few hours ago and the poster had used dependency walker to dig through the SQlite looking for dependencies. Possibly the same poster. It's the Ex suffix that has me puzzled.

Comment: I've stopped using Dependency Walker since it hasn't been updated for a decade and throws a lot of errors that aren't really errors. I will try Process Monitor though I've never used it.

Comment: @NateBarbettini You say SQLite, but I've never worked with it and don't know if SQLite3 and SQLite3ex are the same thing. I tried installing the NuGet Package for SQLite3 but it wouldn't install - complained that my project targets .NET 4.5.1 but there is no assembly reference for that. I don't understand that error. I did install sqlite-netFx451-setup-x86-2013-1.0.101.0.exe - it doesn't see to have made a difference.

Comment: @user4581301 I think that post was mine. I deleted it since there are so many reports of Dependency Walker reporting those missing DLLs erroneously. I am reposting my question here.

Comment: @user4581301 I think it just registered for me what you are saying - you don't relate to the SQLite3Ex.dll - I wouldn't know. It confuses me too since I can't find SQLite3Ex using Google. The SQLite3Ex.dll is contained in this 3rd party DLLs root folder. I think the 3rd party DLL calls it specifically which is maybe why my installation of sqlite-net451 had no effect?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear there. What I'm used to is sqlite either statically linking in to the program or spitting out sqlite.dll. SQLiteEx.dll is new to me. Could be a .net thing, could be a thirdparty port with 'Ex'tended functionality, could be something completely unrelated with an unfortunately similar name. In this I know nothing, so I should have just shut the smurf up.

Comment: @ravuya Process Manager is running through over 2 million events in a very short period of time. Way too fast for me to see anything meaningful - especially since I have no idea what to look for exactly. Based on the Event Viewer log entry I posted, can you tell me how to filter it in Process Manager and eliminate all of the clutter?

Comment: Track down the filter. I think it has an icon that looks like a funnel. Set the left drop-down to "Process name". Set the center drop-down to "is".  in the empty drop-down type in the executable's name. Make sure include is selected in the right-hand drop-down. Click the add button. Click OK. Then run your program. Only it should show up, but there will still be a lot of stuff. You'll be most interested in the stuff at the end, because that's probably where your program is exiting. Looks for the dll it was loading when it gave up.

Comment: @user4581301 Let me clarify my confusion. This is a web application and so I am not sure which app will show the error - devenv, iisexpress or the DLL that VS creates for my web app. I've tried all 3 but not seeing the error specifically. ProcMon is new to me, but it's a very impressive tool. I'll get a lot of use out of it going forward.

Comment: Process Monitor's companion Process Explorer may help you there. It can show a tree of who launched what, and if the process is still live, list all of the open files, DLLs, and a smurfload of other stats. Doesn't do much good on a process that launches and instantly dies, but you can use your old, pre-undocumented-DLL version to find out the name of the process you need to look for, and hopefully use that as the filter for Process Monitor. Will this work? Dunno. Never debugged a webservice. For all I know this stuff is all hidden under a svchost.